# Manually create APA journal cover page

Tags: memoir, apa6, covers

I was wondering how we can manually create a APA journal cover page in the apa6 class format. The APA 6 package is great for the whole document, however, runs into difficulties if you want to create this layout within a larger document, for example, with memoir class (PhD thesis). Therefore, I was wondering how one could manually recreate the cover page (linked below) without using `\maketitle`, `\author`s, APA6 package, etc. This would only need to include the title, authors, abstract, keywords, and author comment. The main document could continue after this in "book" or "memoir" class.

I have attached here some minimal reproducible code and attached below the output (pages 2 and 3). It would be great if we could get all chapter, title page, and footnote onto a page, and have it index properly with TOC and /href.

Kind Regards and Thankyou in advance,
   Conal Monaghan

```
%%%%%%%%% Preamble   %%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
%%%% Some of the formatting things included for APA style within a book %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
% Double or one and a half spacing.
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[unicode=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                  
%%%% Define titles
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{.5em}{}
%%%% Preamble for the APAtitlepage %%%%%
\usepackage{apatitlepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%
\twoauthors{An Author}{Another Author}
\twoaffiliations{A Big University}{Another Big University}
\APAtitle{The Role of Machiavellian Views and Tactics in Psychopathology}
\APAkeywords{philosophy, unreadable, Continental, gibberish, boring}
\APAabstract{Machiavellianism represents a tendency to manipulate and exploit others in a social world perceived to be hostile. Research has been inconsistent regarding psychopathology associated with this aspect of 
personality. This has been partially due to focusing on Machiavellianism as a unidimensional, as opposed to multi- dimensional, construct. Thus, this study aimed to investigate associations between Machiavellianism and psychopathology from a multidimensional perspective. The participants were 1478 US undergraduates aged between 18 and 53 years (M = 19.55, SD = 3.22; 39\% male) and 218 Australian undergraduates aged between 17 and 60 (M = 20.09, SD = 4.56; 33\% male). 
To address psychometric issues in the Mach- IV scale, item analysis and confirmatory factor analyses were used to derive its multidimensional structure. Structural equation modelling tested unique associations of Machiavellian views and tactics with six psychopathological constructs: depression, fear, anxiety, impulsivity, externalising psychopathology,
 and thought dysfunction. Results from the US and Australian samples suggest that Machiavellianism is best viewed as a two-dimensional construct consisting of views and tactics. Furthermore, the US study showed that Machiavellian views uniquely predicted all areas of psychopathology, whereas tactics predicted only externalising domains. 
These findings demonstrate the multidimensional nature of Machiavellianism and highlight its distinctive psychopathological implications.}
\renewcommand{\APAtitleformat}{\LARGE\bfseries} % default is \LARGE
\APAauthornote{Test of the APA Author note funciton}
\APAnote{}


%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\doublespacing  

  Previous chapter. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite. Integer ut congue lectus. Nullam dapibus scelerisque diam, ac convallis dolor convallis non. Sed nec lectus nec sapien interdum commodo nec quis elit. Sed neque augue, pulvinar id imperdiet id, ullamcorper sed sem. Duis pulvinar blandit erat, quis suscipit erat venenatis sit 
amet. Aenean varius aliquam dignissim. Sed tempus consequat sapien et bibendum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas arcu ligula, tincidunt non volutpat nec, luctus ac justo. Donec euismod egestas leo, 
 vel convallis mi accumsan sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas volutpat lacinia justo, dictum iaculis enim scelerisque in. Vestibulum consequat augue in nisl luctus eget ultrices sem blandit. 
 Donec mi risus, rutrum at tempus in, dapibus vel est. Sed eu ullamcorper velit Blah Blah Blah

\singlespacing
\chapter{} % At the moment ghosted because of the APA title we only want to see "Chapter 1" but we could replace the chapter title with the modified APAtitlePage title

\APAmaketitle
\doublespacing


Chapter Body. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite. Integer ut congue lectus. Nullam dapibus scelerisque diam, ac convallis dolor convallis non. Sed nec lectus nec sapien interdum commodo nec quis elit. Sed neque augue, pulvinar id imperdiet id, ullamcorper sed sem. Duis pulvinar blandit erat, quis suscipit erat venenatis sit amet. Aenean varius aliquam dignissim. Sed tempus consequat sapien et bibendum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas arcu ligula, tincidunt non volutpat nec, luctus ac justo. Donec euismod egestas leo, vel convallis mi accumsan sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas volutpat lacinia justo, dictum iaculis enim scelerisque in. Vestibulum consequat augue in nisl luctus eget ultrices sem blandit. Donec mi risus, rutrum at tempus in, dapibus vel est. Sed eu ullamcorper velit Blah Blah Blah



\end{document}
```

[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]

Comment: There's a lot of code behind that to deal with multiple authors and affiliations. Do you need this too?  And which mode of `apa6` should the title page mimic?

Comment: HI @AlanMunn,   Thanks for getting back to this query. The environment that I and a few others would like to mimic would be the journal style. I guess the easiest way would be to do the whole thing manually, thus removing most of the code (at least all the piping), i.e. \centre\bf{My Title}. Therefore, what would be required would only be the central column environment, divided into four sub environments within the \centre.1) bf column for title, 2) twocolumn environ with 2-6 authors+affiliations, abstract paragraph double justified, then the italicised keywords followed by 5 keywords. Thanks!

Comment: @ConalMonaghan I've made a package version which you can try. Let me know if you find any problems. If it seems useful I'll just put it up on CTAN.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if this is generally useful to people, but here's a package which uses the `apa6` code modified to avoid name clashes.  It allows you to create an APA journal style title page.  It leaves most of the `apa6` author and affiliation commands intact, but renames a few. It does nothing with headers and footers, which should be defined in the main document, and does nothing with the `\pagestyle`.

```
 \author -> \APAauthor
 \title -> \APAtitle
 \shorttitle -> \APAshorttitle
 \maketitle -> \APAmaketitle
 \abstract -> \APAabstract
 \keywords -> \APAkeywords
 \authornote -> \APAauthornote
 \note -> \APAnote
```

The following commands have been added:

```
 \APAtitleformat -> defaults to \LARGE
 \APAauthformat -> defaults to \large
 \APAaffilformat -> defaults to {}
```

To use it, put `apatitlepage.sty` in your local `texmf` folder, and then use it as in the following sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apatitlepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\twoauthors{An Author}{Another Author}
\twoaffiliations{A Big University}{Another Big University}
\APAtitle{This is the title of my paper}
\APAkeywords{philosophy, unreadable, Continental, gibberish, boring}
\APAabstract{\kant[1]}
\renewcommand{\APAtitleformat}{\LARGE\bfseries} % default is \LARGE
\begin{document}

\APAmaketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### `apatitlepage.sty`

Code repository: [github.com/amunn/apatitlepage](http://github.com/amunn/apatitlepage)

```
% This is file apatitlepage.sty
% Most code Copyright (C) 2011-2017 by Brian D. Beitzel <brian at beitzel.com>
% Modifications Copyright 2017 by Alan Munn <amunn@msu.edu>
%
% The following code is adapted from the apa6 documentclass. Most of it is copied verbatim except for
% a few name changes to avoid potential document class clashes. It does not do anonymization.
% The following commands have been renamed: (along with their internal versions):
%
% \author -> \APAauthor
% \title -> \APAtitle
% \shorttitle -> \APAshorttitle
% \maketitle -> \APAmaketitle
% \abstract -> \APAabstract
% \keywords -> \APAkeywords
% \authornote -> \APAauthornote
% \note -> \APAnote
%
% The following commands have been added:
%
% \APAtitleformat -> defaults to \LARGE
% \APAauthformat -> defaults to \large
% \APAaffilformat -> defaults to {}
%
% Use \renewcommand to change these formats as needed
% 
%
% All other author/affiliation commands remain the same as in the apa6 class
% Please refer to the documentation of the class for how to use them.
%
%
% This package may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This package has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this package is Alan Munn.
%
% This package consists of the file 
%
% apaptitlepage.sty 
%
%
% Version 1.0 2017/10/10
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2003/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{apatitlepage}[2017/10/10 v1.0 Use apa6 journal title page style in another document.]
% New commands added
\newcommand*\APAtitleformat{\LARGE}
\newcommand*\APAauthformat{\large}
\newcommand*\APAaffilformat{}
% Modified apa6 code starts here
\newcommand*\acksname{Author Note}
\newcommand*\keywordname{Keywords}
\long\def\APAnote#1{\long\def\@APAnote{#1}}
\long\def\APAtitle#1{\long\def\@APAtitle{#1}}
\long\def\APAauthor#1{\long\def\@APAauthor{#1}}
\long\def\APAshorttitle#1{\long\def\@APAshorttitle{#1}}
\long\def\twoauthors#1#2{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}\long\def\@authorTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@APAauthor{#1}}
\long\def\onetwoauthors#1#2#3{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}\long\def\@authorTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@authorThree{#3}\long\def\@APAauthor{#1}}
\long\def\twooneauthors#1#2#3{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}\long\def\@authorTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@authorThree{#3}\long\def\@APAauthor{#1}\def\@twofirst{1}}
\let\threeauthors=\onetwoauthors
\long\def\fourauthors#1#2#3#4{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}\long\def\@authorTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@authorThree{#3}\long\def\@authorFour{#4}\long\def\@APAauthor{#1}}
\long\def\fiveauthors#1#2#3#4#5{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}\long\def\@authorTwo{#2}%%%%
 \long\def\@authorThree{#3}\long\def\@authorFour{#4}\long\def\@authorFive{#5}%    %%
 \long\def\@APAauthor{#1}} %%     2006/01/05 -- added as contributed by Aaron Geller %%
\long\def\sixauthors#1#2#3#4#5#6{\long\def\@authorOne{#1}%                  %% thp 2006/01/05
 \long\def\@authorTwo{#2}\long\def\@authorThree{#3}\long\def\@authorFour{#4}%% thp 2006/01/05
 \long\def\@authorFive{#5}\long\def\@authorSix{#6}\long\def\@APAauthor{#1}}    %% thp 2006/01/05
\long\def\affiliation#1{\long\def\@affil{#1}}
\long\def\twoaffiliations#1#2{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}\long\def\@affilTwo{#2}%
\long\def\@affil{#1}}
\long\def\onetwoaffiliations#1#2#3{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}\long\def\@affilTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@affilThree{#3}\long\def\@affil{#1}}
\long\def\twooneaffiliations#1#2#3{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}\long\def\@affilTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@affilThree{#3}\long\def\@affil{#1}}
\let\threeaffiliations=\onetwoaffiliations
\long\def\fouraffiliations#1#2#3#4{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}\long\def\@affilTwo{#2}%
 \long\def\@affilThree{#3}\long\def\@affilFour{#4}\long\def\@affil{#1}}
\long\def\fiveaffiliations#1#2#3#4#5{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}\long\def\@affilTwo{#2}%%
 \long\def\@affilThree{#3}\long\def\@affilFour{#4}\long\def\@affilFive{#5}%        %%
 \long\def\@affil{#1}} %%     2006/01/05 -- added as contributed by Aaron Geller   %%
\long\def\sixaffiliations#1#2#3#4#5#6{\long\def\@affilOne{#1}%           %% thp 2006/01/05
 \long\def\@affilTwo{#2}\long\def\@affilThree{#3}\long\def\@affilFour{#4}%% thp 2006/01/05
 \long\def\@affilFive{#5}\long\def\@affilSix{#6}\long\def\@affil{#1}}    %% thp 2006/01/05
\long\def\APAnote#1{\long\def\@APAnote{#1}}
\long\def\APAabstract#1{\long\def\@APAabstract{#1}}
\long\def\APAkeywords#1{\long\def\@APAkeywords{#1}}
\long\def\APAauthornote#1{\long\def\@APAacks{#1}}
\def\check@author{%
 \@ifundefined{@APAauthor}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{apatitlepage}{Author not defined}\def\@APAauthor{Author}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@APAtitle}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{apatitlepage}{Title not defined}\def\@APAtitle{Title}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@APAshorttitle}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{apatitlepage}{Short title not defined}\def\@APAshorttitle{INSERT SHORTTITLE COMMAND IN PREAMBLE}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@affil}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{apatitlepage}{Affiliation not defined}\def\@affil{Affiliation}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@APAabstract}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{apatitlepage}{Abstract not defined}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@APAkeywords}{%
  \PackageInfo{apatitlepage}{Keywords not defined}}{}
 \@ifundefined{@authorSix}{%                                   % -- thp 2006/01/05
  \@ifundefined{@authorFive}{%                                 % -- thp 2006/01/05
   \@ifundefined{@authorFour}{%
    \@ifundefined{@authorThree}{%
     \@ifundefined{@authorTwo}{%
     }{\@ifundefined{@affilTwo}{\@error@toomanyauthors}{}}
    }{\@ifundefined{@affilThree}{\@error@toomanyauthors}{}}
   }{\@ifundefined{@affilFour}{\@error@toomanyauthors}{}}
  }{\@ifundefined{@affilFive}{\@error@toomanyauthors}{}}       % -- thp 2006/01/05
 }{\@ifundefined{@affilSix}{\@error@toomanyauthors}{}}         % -- thp 2006/01/05
 \@ifundefined{@affilSix}{%                                    % -- thp 2006/01/05
  \@ifundefined{@affilFive}{%                                  % -- thp 2006/01/05
   \@ifundefined{@affilFour}{%
    \@ifundefined{@affilThree}{%
     \@ifundefined{@affilTwo}{%
     }{\@ifundefined{@authorTwo}{\@error@toomanyaffils}{}}
    }{\@ifundefined{@authorThree}{\@error@toomanyaffils}{}}
   }{\@ifundefined{@authorFour}{\@error@toomanyaffils}{}}
  }{\@ifundefined{@authorFive}{\@error@toomanyaffils}{}}       % -- thp 2006/01/05
 }{\@ifundefined{@authorSix}{\@error@toomanyaffils}{}}         % -- thp 2006/01/05
}
\def\put@one@authaffil#1#2{%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}{\APAauthformat #1\vspace{0in}}%
                        {\\\APAaffilformat #2\vspace{0.05in}\\}\end{center}}}

\newsavebox\auone@box
\newsavebox\autwo@box
\newsavebox\autot@box
\newlength\auone@boxwidth
\newlength\autwo@boxwidth
\newlength\autot@boxwidth

\def\default@d@authaffil#1#2#3#4{%
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\begin{center}{\APAauthformat #1\vspace{0in}}%
                                {\\\APAauthformat #2\vspace{0.05in}\\}\end{center}}%
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\begin{center}{\APAauthformat #3\vspace{0in}}%
                                {\\\APAauthformat #4\vspace{0.05in}\\}\end{center}}}

\def\uneven@d@authaffil#1#2#3#4{%
     \hfill\parbox[t]{\auone@boxwidth}{\begin{center}{\APAauthformat #1\vspace{0in}}%
                                      {\\\APAauthformat #2\vspace{0.05in}\\}\end{center}}\hfill\hfill%
           \parbox[t]{\autwo@boxwidth}{\begin{center}{\APAauthformat #3\vspace{0in}}%
                                      {\\\APAauthformat #4\vspace{0.05in}\\}\end{center}}\hfill}

\def\put@two@authaffil#1#2#3#4{%
     \let\disp@authaffil\default@d@authaffil
     \sbox\auone@box{\begin{tabular}{c}\APAauthformat #1\\\APAauthformat #2\end{tabular}}
     \settowidth{\auone@boxwidth}{\usebox\auone@box}
     \sbox\autwo@box{\begin{tabular}{c}\APAauthformat #3\\\APAauthformat #4\end{tabular}}
     \settowidth{\autwo@boxwidth}{\usebox\autwo@box}
     \ifdim\auone@boxwidth<1.25\columnwidth
      \ifdim\autwo@boxwidth<1.25\columnwidth
       \sbox\autot@box{\usebox\auone@box\hspace{0.4in}\usebox\autwo@box}
       \settowidth{\autot@boxwidth}{\usebox\autot@box}
       \ifdim\autot@boxwidth<\textwidth
        \let\disp@authaffil\uneven@d@authaffil
       \fi
      \fi
     \fi
     \ifdim\auone@boxwidth<\columnwidth
      \ifdim\autwo@boxwidth<\columnwidth
       \let\disp@authaffil\default@d@authaffil
      \fi
     \fi
     \disp@authaffil{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\def\APAmaketitle{
 \check@author
\twocolumn[  % anything appearing within the brackets is set in one-column mode
  \vspace{0.03in}
  \begin{center}
  {\APAtitleformat\@APAtitle}\\
  \vspace{-0.05in}
      \@ifundefined{@authorTwo}{
    % one author-affiliation
      \put@one@authaffil{\@APAauthor}{\@affil}}{
      \@ifundefined{@authorThree}{
    % two authors-affiliations
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}}{
      \@ifundefined{@authorFour}{
    % three authors-affiliations
      \@ifundefined{@twofirst}{
    % first one, then two
      \put@one@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}{\@authorThree}{\@affilThree}
      }{
    % first two, then one
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@one@authaffil{\@authorThree}{\@affilThree}
      }}{
      \@ifundefined{@authorFive}{ % 2006/01/05 as contributed by Aaron Geller
    % four authors-affiliations
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorThree}{\@affilThree}{\@authorFour}{\@affilFour}
      }{                          % 2006/01/05 beginning of Aaron Geller contribution
      \@ifundefined{@authorSix}{ % -- thp 2006/01/05
    % five authors-affiliations
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorThree}{\@affilThree}{\@authorFour}{\@affilFour}%
      \vspace{-0.15in}\\ % thp added negative vertical space
      \put@one@authaffil{\@authorFive}{\@affilFive}
      }{                          % 2006/01/05 end of Aaron Geller contribution
    % six authors-affiliations
    %% --- thp 2006/01/05 beginning of six-author display
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorOne}{\@affilOne}{\@authorTwo}{\@affilTwo}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorThree}{\@affilThree}{\@authorFour}{\@affilFour}\vspace{-0.15in}\\
      \put@two@authaffil{\@authorFive}{\@affilFive}{\@authorSix}{\@affilSix}
    %% --- thp 2006/01/05 end of six-author display
      }}}}}
      \@ifundefined{@APAnote}
       {\vspace{0.07in}}
       {\vspace{0.07in}\\ {\APAauthformat\@APAnote\vspace{0.07in}}}


  \@ifundefined{@APAabstract}
  {\par }
  {\par \parbox{4.6875in}
   {\small \noindent \@APAabstract
     \@ifundefined{@APAkeywords}{}{%
      \par\vspace{0.12in}\raggedright\textit{\keywordname:} \@APAkeywords%
     }%
   }
   \vspace{0.24in}%
  }
  \end{center}
 ]
 \onecolumn
 }
\endinput
```

Comment: Thanks amazing, you rock @alan! way more than I was hoping for, thank you very much, I am sure people will want to use it for combining small app style articles into a bigger one. I just had a few  quick modifications to request. Given there might be several papers (e.g., PhD thesis is 4 papers) into a bigger one, there might be up to 5 defined authors, affiliations, abstracts etc. Therefore, can we set it up with a number indicator (or section). e.g., abstract 1{}, APAauthors1{}, \makeAPAtitle 1. That way we can have each article typeset that way within the larger one?

Comment: could we have the author note at the bottom of the title page in APA style, or even just include the footnote from the current document class. The last request is to have it work with the memoir style. Look great in journal style, however within an existing memoir the formatting gets confused and it would be great if the chapter heading, section heading (paper title), abstract, authors / affiliation, keywords, and note we all on the same page. In memoir they are separated. There should be room if formatted as your example. I attached how the memoir is rendering to the original question.Thanks!

Comment: @ConalMonaghan please edit your question to show the code that produced your images.

Comment: @ConalMonaghan But now you're asking for something that really is different from the original request. If you intend the paper title to be a section, then you need to use `memoir` commands to format sections in that way. This is possible, but makes the package more complicated. (Getting the chapter title and paper title on the same page is trivial; getting the paper title to be a section is more complicated.)

Comment: Thanks for all of your input and time invested here. I have attached some minimal reproducible to the question. All on the same page would be the main aim,  I guess the work around for sectioning would be to have an invisible section and phantom (for /href) for each APA style front page? such as.,   \sectionmark{#1}}
                                                          \invisiblesection{}